# Windows Desktop Search via C#

Tags: c#, sql, search, desktop, wds

Where can I find documentation about WDS, specifically, using SQL queries from C# to query WDS? Are there any resources listing the columns that can be queried from the SystemIndex?
Additionally, I want the query to return the "context" i.e. just like the WDS client does with a few lines from the document where the search terms are found.
I am using WDS 4.0 although I believe that the API for 3+ is the same.  I have checked MSDN and other sites with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted on MSDN forums and got the answer:
Columns or properties that can be searched for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd561977(VS.85).aspx
and
"Summary" information - not context
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760163(VS.85).aspx

This has answered my initial question. Thanks for your responses anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Heres is the resource i've used... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(VS.85).aspx

Also it says this:

"Does Windows Search 4.0 have a new SDK?

The platform for Windows Search 4.0 is unchanged from previous versions of Windows Search. The samples for Windows Search are included in the Windows Vista SP1 SDK. Documentation for developing applications that work with Windows Search can be found on MSDN."

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did look at this MSDN content already - it does not list the columns that can be queried.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Windows Search SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=645300AE-5E7A-4CE7-95F0-49793F8F76E8&displaylang=en), you will find a sample called WSSQL that enables you to do SQL queries against WDS.

Comment: I looked at the SDK samples too - while the highlight how to use the API they do not have any documentation on the API i.e. what columns are available for querying via SQL and how to return the result context.