# File Search API for .NET

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to provide file search functionality in our application. How can I use windows search from .NET so that I needn't do the normal recursive searching myself.

EDIT:
Since I'm working on Win XP, search **should not** be based on indexes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Desktop Search via C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870101/windows-desktop-search-via-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the Windows Search API without using an index as Magnus Johansson says.

What you need to do is to stop the Windows Search service and prevent it from starting (see [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=DHOWW7qG6kIC&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=windows+search+without+index&source=bl&ots=XoYt4QVmxH&sig=WUixW89dyJxWUuuJ7LQrg5uwHQE&hl=en&ei=gCaBSunLA4PQ-Qaq3OGsCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=windows%20search%20without%20index&f=false) for details on that). With the indexing service disabled, Windows Search will default to a real-time search instead.

And since you are working on XP, don't forget to change the `FilterFilesWithUnknownExtensions` value to `1` in the registry at 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\ContentIndex`.

KB309173 states that this will let you search all file types in stead of just the registered ones.